# PHP ldap_search() and CLI ldapsearch return different results

Tags: ldap, ldap-query

When running an ldapsearch command on the command line, it returns tons of results, whereas an equivalent (or so I think) query via PHP returns nothing.

ldapsearch command:

```
ldapsearch -Zx -H ldap://directory.host.ca -D [CREDENTIALS] -w [PASSWORD] -z 0 -l 0 - LLL -b "ou=people,dc=business,dc=ca" "(&(facultyCode=AU)(term="1380")" uid
```

PHP search:

```php
//binding has already happened with the same credentials as used in the CLI command
$filter = '(&(facultyCode=AU)(term="1380"))';
$list   = ldap_search($conn,'ou=people,dc=business,dc=ca',$filter,array('uid'),0,0,0);
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Check the server logs to determine what was transmitted in the search request. The filters may not be equivalent in the two examples. For example, PHP might convert the `"` characters to `'` (single-quote to double-quote). Inside an encoded filter, `'` and `"` are not equivalent.

Also, the shell example using `ldapsearch` would not encode `term="1380"`, but rather `term=1380`, which is not the same as `term="1380"`. In other words, the ldapsearch command is (some shells may escape quoted strings differently):

```
ldapsearch -Zx -H ldap://directory.host.ca \
   -D [CREDENTIALS] -w [PASSWORD] -z 0 -l 0 \
   -LLL -b "ou=people,dc=business,dc=ca" \
   '(&(facultyCode=AU)(term=1380)' uid
```

Comment: I don't have access to the server logs, but I will play around with the quotes & see if I can get them to match.  Thanks.

Comment: Single quotes, double quotes, no quotes - the CLI command always works.  Single quotes, double quotes, double quotes encoded as \22 - always returns 0 results via PHP.  Removing the quotes times out.

Comment: Does the `term` attribute value have double quotes, encoded or otherwise?

Comment: "term" does not have quotes.  It exists as the 4 digits: 1380. "term" is actually an object, not an attribute.  I'm querying my organization's central directory service and that's how they've set it up.  I have another person trying to find out how to properly build the query - so in the meantime I'm just trying to get my PHP code to do the same as the CLI command.

Comment: In your PHP filter, the double-quotes is passed to directory server as part of the attribute value. Use `$filter = '(&(facultyCode=AU)(term=1380))';`

Comment: As I wrote above, removing the quotes from the PHP filter results in a server query time out.  I'm setting the client timeout to 0 (no limit).